# Using Twilio API in Ruby, How to pass parameters between actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio-api

In the ruby controller, I have two methods in the same controller.

```
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController

  def send
      my_variable = xxx
      twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
      twilio_client.send_text(user, message)
  end

  def receive
      response = Twilio::TwiML::MessagingResponse.new
      response.message do |message|
        message.body("Hello World!")
      end
      puts params["Body"]
  end

end
```

The method `send` would send message to the specific user, and the method `receive` receive the message from the user. However, the `my_variable` in the send method lost between actions. I want to use the variable in the `receive` method, but don't know how to do that.

I tried to assign the variable one to a session hash. `session[:variable_one] = variable_one`, and access it in the method receive. But it turns out the session[:variable_one] in the method receive is nil.

I read the documents from Twilio, but still very confuse how to pass the extra parameters.

Could you please have some suggestions on this problem? Thanks so much.

Comment: You're sending someone a text message and they're responding, the only thing in common is the recipient's phone number. You know the number you're sending to in `send` and you know what number is triggering `receive`. You'd store `my_variable` in your database and associate it with the phone number.

Comment: I think, it would be easier if you store the phone number and set a callback in twilio dashboard to map inbound message from the user.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks so much for the suggestion. I think this might be the most practical way to implement this.